# count elements inside a specific html node using jquery method .size()

Tags: jquery, html

i want whenever i press a button inside my table-2 to count how many buttons there are **in the specific  table-1 row**  so i can remove them all, one by one, but not the last one.So i need in some way to climb up to the parent element, count the buttons and then use this path to climb down again and remove the button. Here is my jquery code which works only when i have one table-1 row and not for lot's of table-1 rows.

```
$("table.table-2").on("click","#abstract_day",
             function () {
                    var n =$("button#abstract_day").size();
                    if (n==1) {

                    return false;
                    }else{
                        $(this).parent().parent().parent().remove();
                    };
            });



 <table class="table-1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td>

       <table class="table-2" >                                                       
         <tbody>                                                        
           <tr>                                                        
             <td id="day" >                                                     
               <span>                                                               
                <select class="form-control-2">                                                           
                <option></option>                                                                 
                <option>1</option>                                                                
                <option>2</option>                                                                                                                          
                </select>                                                               
                <button id="add_day" type="button" class="btn btn-default">                                                                                                             
                </button>                                                               
                <button id="abstract_day" type="button" class="btn btn-default">                                                                                                                                
                </button>                                                           
              </span>
             </td>
             </tr>
            </tbody>
         </table>   

        </td>                                                                                                               
      </tr>   
       <tr>
         <td>

          <table class="table-2" >                                                        
           <tbody>                                                      
             <tr>                                                          
              <td id="day" >                                                        
                <span>                                                              
                 <select class="form-control-2">                                                              
                  <option></option>                                                               
                  <option>1</option>                                                                  
                  <option>2</option>                                                                                                                            
                  </select>                                                             
                  <button id="add_day" type="button" class="btn btn-default">                                                                                                               
                  </button>                                                             
                  <button id="abstract_day" type="button" class="btn btn-default">                                                                                                                              
                  </button>                                                         
                  </span>                                                         
                </td>                                                                                                             
              </tr> 
           </tbody>
         </table>

       </td>                                                                                                              
     </tr> 
   </tbody>
 </table>
```

Comment: `$("table td:not(:last)")` all td's except last td

Comment: $("button#abstract_day").size(); what does it give. make sure you have unique ids for each elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood you correctly you could do something like this

```
$("table.table-2").on("click","#abstract_day", function () {
    $(this).closest("tr").find("button").not(":last").remove();
});
```